Styling React react datepicker
I have a date picker on my react app. Which somewhat looks like this: 

Here is the code snippet for the date picker.


     renderDate = () => {
        const { someData } = this.state;

        return (
            <span id="my-date-picker">
                <DatePicker
                    selected={someData}
                    onChange={this.myFunc}
                    showTimeSelect
                    className="form-control"
                    timeIntervals={15}
                    dateFormat={DATE_TIME_PICKER_FORMAT}
                />
            </span>
        );
    };
#my-date-picker li:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f0f0f0;
}



As you can see, I've made a css style for changing the background color of the even time slots of a date.
But, now the main problem is whenever I click on an "even numbered time" let's say 2:15 PM the background color of the date picker remains #f0f0f0 , which I don't want. I want to change the background color of a selected time slot to blue like in the picture.
I tried doing this, but it is still same:
#my-date-picker li:nth-child(even):focus {
    background: blue;
}

I am using 'react-datepicker'

then use the onClick function or the :focus CSS state?

I did. It is still same.
#my-date-picker li:nth-child(even):focus {
    background: blue;
}


I did tried with focus. But It is still same.

No. I didn't got my desired result.

Why :focus? You want the selected time to keep the background color, even after it loses focus again, no? The selected time slot gets the class react-datepicker__time-list-item--selected added, so use that for formatting.

Hey, if the background is the same, try something simple like adding !important to your desired background you want to change?

Please [edit] your question to include the name of the datepicker component you are using. Include a link to the provider's website.

I am using 'react-datepicker'

Check This Out
You can find the className props which you need and try with them to achieve what you want
 () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  let handleColor = (time) => {
    return time.getHours() > 12 ? "text-success" : "text-error";
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      showTimeSelect
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      timeClassName={handleColor}
    />
  );
};

react-datepicker

This is not a reliable source because there is no specified library given in the question, there can be any date picker library being used here, why assume react-datepicker?

@TanishqS in his caption "Styling React react datepicker" also same ui with react-datepicker ?

yea but it does not specifically say the react-datepicker library, and there are a handful of "react datepicker" libraries

alright bro goodluck with it then Styling React react datepicker and react-datepicker have too many differences

Its a good recommendation for a similar issue regarding the library, so upvoted

It has to be react-datepicker in this conditions so he can check the props and make it if it's not he should give package name :p
